# PHP memory limit -1 unlinimited

Tags: php, php-internals, memory-limit

In PHP 5.4 How much memory is allocated to a script, when we set `memory_limit` to -1  ?

Memory exhausted error will not come until all memory is exhausted .

But will this affect my other processes too? What is default memory allocated ? How it increases gradually ?

Would like to know how PHP Internals handling it, when we set `memory_limit` to -1.

Comment: memory_limit set to -1 means that it uses up all the memory it can use. And it will not stop running until your whole ram is exhausted. Basically, it kinda doesn't care about memory usage.

Comment: Why not write a script an see what happens? Which "other processes" are you talking about?